# How can I mark button as active based on the page I am at?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, jinja2

when a user clicks a tab I want that tab to show as active in blue. I can do it using if statements like the one I show on the code, but I would be repeating the code a LOT, so there has to be another way, could someone let me a hand please?

The current if statement shows the profile page which is active

```
<!-- This is saying: inherit everything from __base.html -->
{% extends "storePage/partials/__base.html" %}
<!-- Main base template which contains header and footer too -->
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!-- To beautify the form at signup -->
{% block body %}

<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="list-group ">
                <label class="card-header">Personal Settings</label>
                {% if request.get_full_path == "/settings/profile/" %}
                    <a href="{% url 'profile-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Profile</a>
                {% endif %}

                <a href="{% url 'account-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span> Account</a>
                <a href="{% url 'emails-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Emails</a>
                <a href="{% url 'billing-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span> Billing</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Center-right navBar-->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            {% block settingsPageInfo %} {% endblock %} <!-- Here goes the user information on the profile page -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




{% endblock %}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[[image: Screen-Shot-2019-01-27-at-11-33-38-PM.png]]

How can I do it so when I go to Account it shows blue?

Thanks guys

Comment: Not sure how this would work in python or whatever that code resembles, but the general approach is to create a custom event handler (a click event in this case) and apply it to each tab. Then just use the keyword `this` to add / remove css classes to elements and you're done.

Comment: Ohh so it would be done let’s say with JavaScript in a new file with a file called by convention eventHandler? That can be done right there on that html in python but it would not be neat

Comment: I thought there simpler approach

Comment: In javascript it would be something like `element.addEventListener('click', function(e){ element.classList.add("active"); otherTabElement.classList.remove("active"); });`.

Comment: this has nothing to do with backend (django) this will be done on frontend with javascript ( or jQuery).

Comment: And ye, like @Ahtisham says, using jQuery for this would simplify it a lot as you could "talk" to multiple elements at the same time by classname: `$(".tabClass").removeClass("active");`. It would remove it from all tabs instead of having to individually target each one (or using a loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to match your request URL name with your current URL, you can add active class like this or directly to the  tag.

```
<ul>
  <li class="{% if 'profile' in request.resolver_match.url_name %} active {% endif %}">
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This should solve your question:

```
<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="list-group ">
            <label class="card-header">Personal Settings</label>
            {% if request.get_full_path == "/settings/profile/" %}
                <a href="{% url 'profile-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if 'profile' in request.resolver_match.url_name %} active {% endif %}"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Profile</a>
            {% endif %}

            <a href="{% url 'account-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if 'account' in request.resolver_match.url_name %} active {% endif %}"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span> Account</a>
            <a href="{% url 'emails-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if 'emails' in request.resolver_match.url_name %} active {% endif %}"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Emails</a>
            <a href="{% url 'billing-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if 'billing' in request.resolver_match.url_name %} active {% endif %}"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span> Billing</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Center-right navBar-->
    <div class="col-md-9">
        {% block settingsPageInfo %} {% endblock %} <!-- Here goes the user information on the profile page -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems interesting, thanks. Tomorrow when I wake up I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

create a common component like this

```
<angular-anchor-tag [url]="link1"></angular-anchor-tag>
```

angular-anchor-tag.html

```
<div>
 <a href="url" class="link" (click)="highlightFunction($event)">
<div>
```

angular-anchor-tag.ts

```
 @Input url; 
    highlightFunction(event){

    //remove all the highlight classes from links
    .$("link").removeClass("highlight");

    add highlight class to the events target
    event.target.addClass('highlight');

    }
```